# React routing optional parameter not working (react-router-dom: version 4.1.2)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My AdministratePage shows a collection of users. In order to administrate a given user I'm trying to apply an optional parameter, like so:

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<Route path="/admin" component={AdministratePage} >    
  <Route path="/:id" component={AdministratePage} />
</Route>
```

The route **/admin** works fine and shows the AdministratePage.
However using a parameter eg /admin/abc
results in a blank page.

I also tried the following syntax:

```
<Route path="/admin/:id?" component={AdministratePage} />
```

.. without luck.

My AdministratePage is not yet configured for filtering, so it should just display all users for the moment.

For what it's worth: my webpack.config.js contains:

```
 devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
```

I'm using "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2".
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Route path="/admin" component={AdministratePage} />
<Route path="/admin/:id" component={AdministratePage} />
```

Comment: Still  no luck. The former shows AdministratePage ok, the latter a blank page.

Comment: Hmm, what if you add `exact`. `<Route exact path="/admin" component={AdministratePage} />`

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was that the bundle was not found.

See [React routing, path not working, bundle not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275901/react-routing-path-not-working-bundle-not-found). I hope it might help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your `index.html` you are using an absolute path for the `bundle.js`, as `<script src="/bundle.js" />` and not `<script src="bundle.js" />`